# Import CSV into SQL Server database, keeping ID column values

Tags: sql-server, intellij-idea

I am working to migrate a SQLite database to SQL Server and I need to use IntelliJ IDEA to import all the data from the SQLite tables in to the MSSQL database.

I have exported the data to CSV format, but when I import into SQL Server, I need to maintain the existing ID columns (as foreign keys refer to it).

Normally, I can do this by executing `SET IDENTITY_INSERT xxx ON;` prior to my `INSERT` statements.

However, I do not know how to do this when importing CSV using IntelliJ.

The only other option I see is to export the data as a series of SQL INSERT statements, but that is very time consuming as the schemas between the two databases are slightly different (not to mention the SQL syntax).

Is there another way to import this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to perform an Identity Insert ON in an IntelliJ query, but I do know how to work around this problem.  Import your data into a temporary table destination, then execute a query within SQL Server that

- Sets Identity Insert ON
- Inserts the data from the temporary table into the final destination
- Sets Identity Insert OFF

What this really does is prevent you from having to spend (potentially) hours finding out how to implement an Identity Insert ON in IntelliJ when you may never need to do this again. It is straightforward and simple to code as well.

However, if you want to learn if there is a way to do this in IntelliJ, go for it. That would be a more optimal method.

Comment: To avoid confusion, I would call it staging table and not temporary. Otherwise 100% agree with recommendation.